# MySQL accessing previous row values

Tags: mysql

I have two columns `Page_from` and `Page_to`. When the records are sorted, they appear as...

```
Page_from   Page_to
1              4
5              7
9              11
```

Here page number 8 is missing.
I want to find the missing page number.So I must be able to compare the value of `Page_to` in previous row with `Page_from` in current row.

Comment: This will require a self-join

Comment: Post us a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your table schema with some data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the beginning of a missing sequence by finding the previous record, and comparing the previous `page_to` and the current `page_from`.  If there is a gap, you can get both the first and last page in the gap.

```
select tprev.page_to + 1 as missing_page_from, t.page_from - 1 as missing_page_to
from (select t.*,
             (select tprev.page_to
              from t tprev
              where tprev.page_from < t.page_from
              limit 1
             ) as prev_to
      from t
     ) t
where prev_to is not null and
      prev_to <> t.page_from - 1;
```